# create as select in oracle

Tags: oracle

I have a little question about creating a table using another tables.

my code:

```
create table TB_OLAP_TELEFONIA as 

select   ID                AS LOG_ID,
         HORAFIM           AS LOG_HORA,
         DURACAO           AS LOG_DURA,
         TO_CHAR( HORAFIM, 'D')  AS LOG_DIA_SEMANA,
         TO_NUMBER( SUBSTR( NUMEROA, 3, 1 ) ) AS LOG_NUMA_TIPO,
         TO_NUMBER( SUBSTR( NUMEROA, 3, 1 ) ) AS LOG_NUMB_TIPO,
         SUBSTR( NUMEROA, 1, 2) ) AS LOG_NUMA_ESTADO,          
         SUBSTR( NUMEROA, 1, 2) ) AS LOG_NUMB_ESTADO

from     DADOS_COLUNA_OLAP
```

The sintax are incorrect, and I can't remember what use on the "as" place to give the correct name to column.

Some good glue?
Thanks!

Comment: You can't remember the syntax?  Was the Oracle reference site down?  Unavailable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Too much ) )

```
create table TB_OLAP_TELEFONIA as 

select   ID                AS LOG_ID,
         HORAFIM           AS LOG_HORA,
         DURACAO           AS LOG_DURA,
         TO_CHAR( HORAFIM, 'D')  AS LOG_DIA_SEMANA,
         TO_NUMBER( SUBSTR( NUMEROA, 3, 1 ) ) AS LOG_NUMA_TIPO,
         TO_NUMBER( SUBSTR( NUMEROA, 3, 1 ) ) AS LOG_NUMB_TIPO,
         SUBSTR( NUMEROA, 1, 2 ) AS LOG_NUMA_ESTADO,          
         SUBSTR( NUMEROA, 1, 2 ) AS LOG_NUMB_ESTADO

from     DADOS_COLUNA_OLAP
```

Answer (score 3):

The CTAS syntax is correct.  Your problem is a cut'n'paste error.  Replace

```
 SUBSTR( NUMEROA, 1, 2) ) AS LOG_NUMA_ESTADO,
 SUBSTR( NUMEROA, 1, 2) ) AS LOG_NUMB_ESTADO
```

with

```
 SUBSTR( NUMEROA, 1, 2)  AS LOG_NUMA_ESTADO, 
 SUBSTR( NUMEROA, 1, 2)  AS LOG_NUMB_ESTADO
```

**edit**

While I'm at it I should point out that you are substringing the same column twice, but with different aliases.  Did you mean to do this?

```
 SUBSTR( NUMEROA, 1, 2)  AS LOG_NUMA_ESTADO, 
 SUBSTR( NUMEROB, 1, 2)  AS LOG_NUMB_ESTADO
               ^
```

If so, you need top fix the column name in both places.